# Metamask not connecting to localhost "7545"

Tags: truffle, testrpc

After following the pet shop tutorial i cant connect my localhost to the metamask wallet i'm still get 0eth in my wallet whereas it should be 99eth after connecting. The metamask is not showing it as private network.[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing magic about this: it should work flawlessly.

Apparently I do not see your 0x55...363A (presented by metamask) address in the list of ganache. It does not assign 100 eth to all the account existing in the world, but to those created at startup only.

Add one of the ganache addresses to metamask using its private key and you should see 100 eth immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your metamask has a different port configured to localhost.  Go to the dropdown menu at the top of the metamask window and select "custom rpc".  On the left menu, go to where it says localhost 8545 (it might be a different number, definitely not 7545 - which is the problem).  Change the port number in the network name to "7545" and do the same for the port number at the end of the url underneath it (new rcp url).  This should fix the problem immediately.